# Android 4.2 Material TextInputLayout hint not showing in rtl mode

Tags: android, material-design

floating hint in Material TextInputLayout not showing when switching rtl mode,
when locale is ltr everything is ok:
[LTR MODE, FLOATING HINT IS WORKING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QXV6.jpg)

but in rtl its gone:
[RTL MODE AND NO HINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I808k.jpg)

---

This is part of my XML:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/code_text_input"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/login">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/code_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/activate_code"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="@dimen/large_text" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---

I got something.
the problem is with farsi or arabic string. but it works even in RTL mode when string is Latin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it.
I used newest library of material design

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02
```

I changed it to

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05
```

and everything is well.

Comment: It works..thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I got this case before, applying rtl to show Arabic text for example.

I used this xml:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:hint="@string/phone_number_label" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Note that, if you would like to show Arabic text, you should make a **strings.xml** file for locale Arabic.

Comment: I`ve made fa values folder and i'm setting fa locale. but of course the hint is not sowing in farsi locale